# One tap sign in not working after release

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, google-play-console, google-one-tap

The production app gives me `Developer console is not set up correctly.`
even thought the i set up an oauth 2.0 client in the google cloud console with the app signing sha1 fingerprint

So i wanted to integrate one tap google sign in on my android application, and because i have a testing production environment(app center) i created one oauth client for the app center prod.I use the fingerprint sha1 of the upload keys, that google uses to verify the apk/bundle upload. This scenario described above works fine.

Now i wanted to release the app but before releaasing(few days ago) i created a second oauth client
with the google play app sign sha1 that Google handles automatically. But now the app is released it says developer console not configured correctly. It does not make sense since Google is resigning the app after with their app sign key so supposingly it should work. All the guides say that this is the fix. But it does not seem to work.
Some extra info:
Both of these oauth clients have the same package name but different fingerprint.
The debug prod never had an issue or problem ever
I dont have  a firebase project
I recently one week ago i updated both my release signing key and uploaded keys.